# Stop sending mail to myself when choosing Reply All in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, alias, reply

My company has set up each mail account with serveral aliases.  My default account is `firstL@mycompany.com`.  I also have:

- `first.last@mycompany.com`
- `flast@mycompany.com`
- `first_last@mycompany.com`

The problem is: My account uses the default to sign in and recieve e-mail, `firstL@mycompany.com`.  But, people will send mail to one of my aliases and when I click "reply to all", it sends the e-mail back to me.

How do I configure Outlook (2010) to ignore the reply to all so it doesn't send my own replies to my own account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't configure that.

But you could add a rule to delete messages you receive from yourself (or move them to another folder).