# Excluding a recipient when sending mail via Outlook to a PDL

Tags: microsoft-outlook, distribution-list

Based on an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/155241/stop-sending-mail-to-myself-when-choosing-reply-all-in-outlook-aliases/155331#155331) to a similar [question](https://superuser.com/q/155241/978), what I am trying to accomplish may not be possible without using an Outlook rule.

Is it possible to avoid sending myself an email when sending to an internal distribution list that I am a member of with Outlook?

Is this perhaps configurable in Exchange if not in Outlook?